# Как добавить сноски в CKEDITOR5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor

уже 3 дня убил чтоб подключить сноски к плагину CKEDITOR5, но всё никак.
Получается добавить значек сносок, но функционал не работает, выдаёт ошибку **ckeditor-duplicated-modules**.
Плагин нашел вот такой - *[ссылка](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-footnote)*
Подскажите как правильно это всё должно работать и подключаться.
Сам проект на laravel

Comment: решено. но если что, оставлю это тут. может кому пригодится.
этот плагин работает с модулями v.17.0.0 может быть и до 20.0.0 можно будет дотянуть, не проверял. но на 22.0.0 не работает уже. поэтому когда выкачиваем ckeditor5-build-classic, то настраиваем там в package.json все версии на ^17.0, повторюсь, может и выше версии можно взять, но на 22.0.0 уже не работает. далее как настроили package.json удаляем папку node_modules и запускаем npm run build и вуаля, получаем наш собраный файлик который смело запихиваем в корень вашего проекта.
ВАЖНО! Удалите node_modules внутри ckeditor5-footnote

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ваше решение! На версиях 26.0.0 тоже не работает. Я бы ещё добавил, что требование к версии 17.0.0 относится также ко всем пакетам, которые устанавливаются в дальнейшем. Установил пакет font последней версии и поймал ту же ошибку ckeditor-duplicated-modules. Удаление и установка пакет font@17.0.0 решила проблему.